# How to reload web site each time the app is called

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and I am trying to find a way to make a app that loads my web site each time it is called  Below is my code and it works great the first time but if I go back into the app the 2nd time it displays the app view and not the web site.  I guess the onCreate is not the right funcation to use can someone please help me

```
public class mysite extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String url = "http://www.mysite.com";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: If this is resolved, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your app probably isn't exiting, it's just hiding... You likely want onResume() not onCreate()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: i am getting application has stopped unexpectedly and then it force close but the site does display!

Answer (score 0):

This documentation on the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) should answer your question for you.

`onCreate` is called each time the Activity is created.  If you go to a different activity and go back, you can't guarantee that it will be recreated or not.  If you want something to run every time the activity is started, you should put it in `onResume`.

Comment: if I put it on the resume I get a message that the app has stopped inexpressibility and o force close.  its do to the web site being slow.  I need a workaround for this.

Comment: Are you sure that is what is causing the exception?  Look at logcat to see the full stacktrace.

Comment: i am getting application has stopped unexpectedly and then it force close but the site does display

Comment: Please use logcat to see why it force closed.  To do so, in eclipse go to the DDMS perspective or open the logcat view.  Or, run adb logcat from the command line.

Comment: Mayra, do you have googeletalk?

Comment: I dont know why if I put it on the onResume it crashs. How about if I do it on the onCreate but then send a comment to close the app??  can anyone tell me that

Comment: You need to post the logcat logs of the crash before anyone can help you further.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat or http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html for how to get logcat output.

Comment: Mayra its to big to post can I email you it

Comment: I got it working.  thanks everyone I had to add super.onResume(); to the onResume